# Set ListView ItemTemplate and get ObservableCollection related object

Tags: .net, wpf, listview, observablecollection, itemssource

I have a `ListView` and i set its `ItemsSource` property to an `ObservableCollection` of:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So:

```
ObservableCollection data = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
MyList.ItemsSource = data;
```

This is my `ListView`:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyList">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Click="Button_Click"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Now i add a new Item to my ObservableCollection and I catch the Button_Click event:

```
Item item1 = new Item();
item1.Name = "item1";
data.Add(item1);

private void Button_Click(Button sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // How to get item1 here from sender?
}
```

So, i want to get the Item relative to the button I clicked. How could i do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Item` will be in the `DataContext` of the `ListViewItem` and in the `Button` too:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    Item item = button.DataContext as Item;
}
```